# proof of property of exponential distribution, using taylor polynomial

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, taylor-expansion

I want to prove that if we have an exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$, we have that $P(X \le x)=\lambda x + o(x)$. I want to do this by using Taylor-series and the lagrange remainder theorem. There is one detail that I am not able to complete, basically, I can only show that this holds for an interval $[0,a]$ for any $a$, but not $[0, \infty)$.

Here are my details.

I need to show that 
$1-e^{-\lambda x}=\lambda x+o(x)$

The n taylor polynomial on any interval [0,a] becomes:

$\Sigma_{1}^n[\frac{(-1)^{n+1}\lambda^n*x^n}{n!}]$
. The remainder term is $\frac{(-1)^{n+2}\lambda^{n+1}*e^{-\lambda c}x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$, for a c in the interval.
An upper bound for this is: $\frac{\lambda^{n+1}*a^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$, and this goes to zero in our interval. I have two problems now:

**1.I almost have my result, but the problem is that n is not bounded, if the sum was finite I see from $\Sigma_{1}^n[\frac{(-1)^{n+1}\lambda^n*x^n}{n!}]$ that I would get $\lambda x + o(x)$. But if the sum was infintie how can I then be sure that last parts of the sum will be o(x)?, what I mean is, if you add a finite number of variables whose limit is 0, then this limit is 0, but this does not hold for an infinite sum?**

**2. I only proved in on an interval [0,a], how do I extend it to $[0,\infty)$?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivative of the function $u$ defined by $u(x)=\mathrm e^{-\lambda x}$ is such that $u'(x)=-\lambda \mathrm e^{-\lambda x}$. By Taylor formula, for every nonnegative $x$, there exists some $z(x)$ in $[0,x]$ such that $u(0)-u(x)=-xu'(z(x))$, that is, $1-\mathrm e^{-\lambda x}=\lambda x\mathrm e^{-\lambda z(x)}$. When $x\to0$, $z(x)\to0$ hence $\mathrm e^{-\lambda z(x)}\to1$. This proves the result.

> I only proved in on an interval [0,a], how do I extend it to [0,∞)?

Sorry but I fail to understand this question.

Comment: The last thing I asked about was not important I think. Because I wanted to show that the formula holds on the enitre real line, not just a closed interval, but we look at limit when it goes to zero, so I guess it is ok. But I see that you proved that $1-e^{-\lambda x} \rightarrow \lambda x$, since $e^{-\lambda z(x)}\rightarrow 1$, but how does this show that $1-e^{-\lambda x}=\lambda x + o(x)$? I mean, then you need an equality, don't you?(I mean you have a limit not an equality?)

Comment: And don't we also need to show that what we have in addition to $\lambda x$, goes to zero much faster than $\lambda x$, that is $\frac{o(x)}{x}\rightarrow 0$? Can $\lambda x e^{-\lambda z(x)}$,be rewritten so that $\lambda x e^{-\lambda z(x)}=\lambda x +o(x)$?

Comment: No this does not prove that $1-\mathrm e^{-\lambda x}\to\lambda x$ when $x\to0$, which would be absurd. Instead, this answer proves that $1-\mathrm e^{-\lambda x}=\lambda xu(x)$ for every $x$, with $u(x)\to1$ when $x\to0$. Note that any function $a$ is such that $a(x)=\lambda x+o(x)$ when $x\to0$ if and only if $a(x)=\lambda xb(x)$ with $b(x)\to1$ when $x\to0$ hence (amazingly...) the post answers exactly the question asked.

Comment: Oh, I see, I didn't understand that those those ways of writing a(x) was completely equal, thanks.